# Why isn't omit() removing the undefined values after mapping?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using the following Lodash chained utilities to map/flat and array and produce a new one while excluding the undefined valued.

```
const array = _(resp.data)
   .omit(_.isUndefined)
   .flatMap('building')
   .value()
console.log(array)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the undefined values are still being included. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

resp.data looks like this

```
[
  { username: '', building: [ name: '' ] }
  { username: '', building: [ name: '' ] }
  // etc...
]
```

**EDIT2:**

Those `undefined` values are probably the empty `building` that come objects have.

Comment: It would be wise to include what `resp.data` is.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `undefined` value should belong to a `user` in the `resp.data` where no `building` exist. All you have to do is to `_.filter()` all values that are `undefined` through `_.identity()` after the `_.flatMap()`.

Note: Using `_.omit` should only be used against objects, using this in the context of an array (e.g. `_.flatMap()` which results in an array) would yield a result of an object wherein the index of each item is it's index in the array. You should use `_.filter()` instead.

```js
var data = [
  { username: 'user1', building: [ { name: 'building1' } ] },
  { username: 'user2', building: [ { name: 'building2' } ] },
  { username: 'user3' }
];

var result = _(data)
  .flatMap('building')
  .filter(_.identity)
  .value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const array = _(resp.data)
.omit(_.isUndefined)
.flatMap('building')
.map()
.omit(_.isUndefined)
.value()
```

Comment: After doing that I get something weird like this: `Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: undefined}`

Comment: try it now i have changed some thing